# Change member function to const silently breaks code

Tags: c++

I'm writing a interface to a 3rd party library. It manipulates objects through a C interface which essentially is a `void*`. Here is the code simplified:

```
struct LibIntf
{
    LibIntf() : opaquePtr{nullptr} {}

    operator void *()  /* const */ { return opaquePtr;  }     
    operator void **()             { return &opaquePtr; }

    void *opaquePtr;
};

int UseMe(void *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == (void *)0x100)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void CreateMe(void **ptr)
{
    *ptr = (void *)0x100;
}

int main()
{
    LibIntf lib;

    CreateMe(lib);
    return UseMe(lib);
}
```

Everything works great until I add the `const` on the `operator void *()` line. The code then defaults silently to using the `operator void **()` breaking the code.

My question is why?

I'm returning a pointer through a function that doesn't modify the object. Should be able to mark it `const`. If that changes it to a `const` pointer, the compiler should error because `operator void **()` shouldn't be a good match for function `CallMe()` that just want a `void *`.

Comment: Try creating const and non-const versions of each operator, e.g., `operator const void*() const` and `operator void*()` (and the same for the `void**` variation).  Also, shouldn't `UseMe` accept a `const void*`?

Comment: I think the compiler is happy with the void** conversion because you can convert any pointer to void *, if you do not want that, is there a way to use a different type? Otherwise I think grek40's link explains everything.

Comment: @Phil, UseMe is defined by the 3rd party. I can't change the signature.

Comment: @JackSanga Ah OK my misunderstanding.  Skipped over the details in a rush to try to make a helpful comment. :-)

Comment: @JackSanga still, the comment from Phil is close to a solution approach. Define both overloads of the conversion... `operator void const*() const` __and__ `operator void*()` and maybe even add a const overload for `void const* const*`

Comment: @grek40 no reason to define the operator const if it will never be called. None of the 3rd party calls expect a const. Thanks to everybody who contributed.

Comment: @JackSanga this is not about the 3rd party... the difference is, whether the instance of your struct is const. If it is, it will only apply const conversion operators, otherwise it will prefer the not-const ones over the const ones even when the returned converted type needs another conversion. However, if your question is no longer *why* but *how to deal with it*, then the duplicate is not a perfect match anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the standard says should happen, but this is far from obvious. For quick readers, jump to the "How to fix it?" at the end.

### Understanding why the `const` matters

Once you add the `const` qualifier, when you call `UseMe` with an instance of `LibIntf`, the compiler have the two following possibilities:

1. `LibIntf` →<sup>1</sup> `LibIntf` →<sup>2</sup> `void**` →<sup>3</sup> `void*` (through `operator void**()`)
2. `LibIntf` →<sup>3</sup>  `const LibIntf` →<sup>2</sup> `void*` →<sup>1</sup> `void*` (through `operator void* const()`)

<sup>1)</sup> No conversion needed.
<sup>2)</sup> User-defined conversion operator.
<sup>3)</sup> Legal conversions.

Those two conversion paths are legal, so which one to choose?
The standard defining C++ answers:

> #### [`[over.match.best]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best)
>
> Define `ICSi(F)` as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - let `ICSi(F)` denote the implicit conversion sequence that converts the `i`th argument in the list to the type of the `i`th parameter of viable function F. [`[over.best.ics]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics) defines the implicit conversion sequences and [`[over.ics.rank]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank) defines what it means for one implicit conversion sequence to be a better conversion sequence or worse conversion sequence than another.
>
> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a
>   better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments
>   `i`, `ICSi(F1)` is not a worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, and then
>
> - for some argument `j`, `ICSj(F1)` is a better conversion sequence than `ICSj(F2)`, or, if not that,
> - the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see [`[dcl.init]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init), [`[over.match.conv]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.conv), and [`[over.match.ref]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref)) and the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F1` to the destination type (i.e., the type of the entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F2` to the destination type.

(I had to read it a couple times before getting it.)

This all means *in your specific case* than option #1 is *better* than option #2 because for user-defined conversion operators, the conversion of the return type (`void**` to `void*` in option #1) is considered **after** the conversion of the parameter type (`LibIntf` to `const LibIntf` in option #2).

In chain, this means in option #1 there is nothing to convert (latter in the conversion chain, there will but this is not yet considered) but in option #2 a conversion from `non-const` to `const` is needed. Option #1 is, thus, dubbed *better*.

### How to fix it?

Simply remove the need to consider the `non-const` to `const` *conversion* by *casting* the variable to `const` (explicitly (casts are always explicit (or are called conversions))):

```
struct LibIntf
{
    LibIntf() : opaquePtr{nullptr} {}

    operator void *()  const { return opaquePtr;  }     
    operator void **()       { return &opaquePtr; }

    void *opaquePtr;
};

int UseMe(void *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == (void *)0x100)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void CreateMe(void **ptr)
{
    *ptr = (void *)0x100;
}

int main()
{
    LibIntf lib;
    CreateMe(lib);

    // unfortunately, you cannot const_cast an instance, only refs & ptrs
    return UseMe(static_cast<const LibIntf>(lib));
}
```

Comment: See the following example for the difference between const/non-const overloads: https://ideone.com/4oUVmK. IMO `LibIntf2` there would be the correct one, no need to const-cast the instances on every usage.

Comment: @grek40 Ho yeah that's better (I thought you meant to define const and non-const operator for both void* and void**). It's better, but it is still weird.

Comment: @YSC basic guideline to account for the strange overload resolution: always define the non-const conversion, optionally define the const conversion as additional operator instead of a replacement.